# Sending arrays as query parameters to express does not work

Tags: express

I think that one should be able to send a url like this to express:

```
/?some_arr[]=1&some_arr[]=2
```

and get in req.query: `{some_arr: ['1','2']}`

but I tried it and I get: `{some_arr: '2'}`

Is this how it is supposed to be? What can be wrong? Is there any config settings to enable the array feature?

This is in an existing, large project. Could this have been turned off in some way?

Comment: Express 4 (it uses `qs` to parse query string by default, which [supports arrays](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#parsing-arrays)) will do exactly as you expect (`{ some_arr: [ '1', '2' ] }`), unless you explicitly turned off that behaviour or, possibly, if you're using an older version of Express.

Comment: Check out application settings as query parser might have been customized there. See http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.set ... pay special attention to setting `query parser`.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the project since earlier had the line `app.use(hpp());` which apparently is a package to explicitly remove the array feature...

Answer (score -1):

do something like that-

```
/?some_arr=1&some_arr=2
```

and now on your express code-

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.query) // 
   res.send(200)
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I did, and it did not work as expected.

Comment: I think you can differentiate between `/?some_arr[]=1&some_arr[]=2` and `/?some_arr=1&some_arr=2`